# Github packages for repository showing empty page

Tags: github, github-packages

I have followed a few github package blogs, including githubs quickstart: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/quickstart

and I can't seem to navigate to the package page for the repository.  Or I can't view them for some reason. I don't know what is wrong, but the links show up in the repository listing, but on the repository dashboard it shows no packages. And following the link just gives me the page that shows quickstart links for different types of packages.

[repositories have package links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sucrz.png)

[Empty package page following link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvgSa.png)

[no packages on repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlbgU.png)

I'm not sure what I'm missing, it seems like the packages should be listed here.

Comment: Hi @sean-davis, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please provide repository URLs? It could make the help process easier.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.